# Mysql count columns values based on condition

Tags: mysql, count, conditional-statements

I have a table with columns `day`, `month`, `year`, `total_payments`. And I have to calculate `total_payments` according to `days`, `months`, `years`.

How can I calculate values?

I am thinking code like :

```
select 
    month, year, sum(total_payments) 
from 
    webassignment.subscription_stats 
group by 
    day;

select 
    month, year, sum(total_payments) 
from 
    webassignment.subscription_stats 
group by 
    month;

select 
    month, year, sum(total_payments) 
from 
    webassignment.subscription_stats 
group by 
    year;
```

but it will not return the correct answers. And I want to calculate `total_payments` daywise, monthwise, yearwise. Please help me to find values.

Sample input :

```
Day Month   Year    Total_payments
10  01      2008    10
10  01      2008    20
11  02      2008    10
10  03      2010    10
```

Output:

Daywise :

```
day month year total_payments
-----------------------------
10  01    2008 30
11  02    2008 10
10  03    2010 10
```

Same for month and yearwise

Comment: Can you also provide some sample data with expected results?

Comment: Please edit your post to add the sample data there. It is not recommended to post sample data in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a summary with Totals by Year, Month and Day using GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP:

```
SELECT
    `Year`,
    `Month`,
    `Day`,
    SUM(`Total_payments`) as `Totals`
FROM `webassignment`.`subscription_stats`
GROUP BY `Year`,`Month`,`Day` WITH ROLLUP;
```

If you want individual queries for Year, Month and Day:

By Year:

```
SELECT
    `Year`,
    SUM(`Total_payments`) as `Totals`
FROM `webassignment`.`subscription_stats`
GROUP BY `Year`
ORDER BY `Year;
```

By Month:

```
SELECT
    `Year`,
    `Month`,
    SUM(`Total_payments`) as `Totals`
FROM `webassignment`.`subscription_stats`
WHERE `Year` = 2017
GROUP BY `Year`,`Month`
ORDER BY `Year`,`Month`;
```

By Day:

```
SELECT
    `Year`,
    `Month`,
    `Day`,
    SUM(`Total_payments`) as `Totals`
FROM `webassignment`.`subscription_stats`
GROUP BY `Year`,`Month`,`Day`
ORDER BY `Year`,`Month`,`Day`;
```

Comment: Sloan Thrasher this query works nice for years.but for months can i get only single total values according to month-years. Because it gives multiple rows for same year and months. and then i also have to count again for same years and months

Comment: There are 4 queries in my answer. Which one are you talking about? Also, I should have added order by clauses that match the group by clauses on the last 3 queries.

Comment: The months query should return one row for each Year/Month combination. If you want Months from all years (max 12 rows in the result), drop the column Year from the group by. If you want to limit to months in a single year, add a where clause.

Comment: i am talking about 3rd query which gives result for months. actually it works fine but as you have used group by year and month it gives same years and months rows multiple times.here for months i just want single row for month of some year like : (month-year,total_payments) = (02-2008,30)

Comment: ok. but which condition i have to add in where clause for making it monthwise.and i can not add static value 2017. i want this for all records

Comment: That doesn't make sense. How can you limit to a specific year if you don't tell it which year? The query without the where clause will return all months for all years.

Comment: ok. i will use this query inside loop that know about each years.

Answer (score 0):

A way could be the use on an union for show the different result based  on different group by level

```
  select day, month,year,sum(total_payments) 
  from webassignment.subscription_stats group by day, month,year
  union 
  select null, month,year,sum(total_payments) 
  from webassignment.subscription_stats group by month,year
  union 
  select null, null ,year,sum(total_payments) 
  from webassignment.subscription_stats group by year
  order by year, month, day
```

for the sample you provided should be enough

```
  select day, month,year,sum(total_payments) 
  from webassignment.subscription_stats group by day, month,year
  order by day, month,year
```

Comment: Thank for giving answer scaisEdge. but this query does not work properly

Comment: this is mainly a suggestion for a possible solution  .. you have error ? or the result is not like you prefer ?-- any way answer  updated  for your sample